# How to get the save query in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

How can I get the sql executed when I am saving some data? For example,

```
 $user = New User;
 $user->name = "test";
 $user->mail = "test@example.com";
 $user->save();
```

I DON'T want to execute the query. I just want to get the query string.(something like "INSERT INTO users.....")

I have tried `$user->toSql();`. But it gives "select * from users" which is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`toSql();` is for the model query builder. so that's why when you do `$user->toSql();` you get select all statement.

you can do two things here

one, use `DB::listen`

```php
    DB::listen(function ($query) {
        echo $query->sql;
    });
 $user = New User;
 $user->name = "test";
 $user->mail = "test@example.com";
 $user->save();
```

two, QueryLog if you need more details.

```php
DB::enableQueryLog();
 $user = New User;
 $user->name = "test";
 $user->mail = "test@example.com";
 $user->save();
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

if you do not want to run the query, just wrap it with `DB::pretend` just like when you do migration adding `--pretend`, so that you will not migrate the `DB` you will get all the `sql` scripts.

```php
    DB::pretend(function () {
         $user = New User;
         $user->name = "test";
         $user->mail = "test@example.com";
         $user->save();
    });
```

Comment: In both cases, the query is executing. Is there any way to get only the query string without executing it?